# fetching mysql vector over php in json format to Android jsonarray returns null

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, vector

I am decoding/parsing JSON over http fetch and on android I get null results, while on a browser I get the following, which is valid JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "KEY": "-2.71208569845,-1.46780473499, ..."
    }
]
```

where the array is a long list of double values I store as a medium blob in a mysql db. In android, I get this no matter what I try:

```
[{"KEY":""}]
```

I've tried changing between httpget and httppost, and looked at may other posts on SO and tried their suggestions, to no avail.  Here is the PHP:

```
<snip>
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$result=mysql_query("SELECT avgfftspectrum FROM `TremCamTbl` WHERE 
             email='".$_REQUEST['email']."'
             ORDER BY subjectid DESC LIMIT  1");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //$response["KEY"] = array(); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fftdata[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
        /*$data = $row["avgfftspectrum"];  I have also tried these two lines
        **array_push($response["KEY"], $data); */
    }
    echo json_encode($fftdata);
} 
<snip>
```

My android HttpPost or HttpGet look more or less like:

```
<snip>
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
HttpPost httpPost  = new HttpPost(WebConstants.getCloudavgfftUrl()+"?"+paramString);
Log.i(TAG, ""+WebConstants.getCloudavgfftUrl()+"?"+paramString);
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost,responseHandler);
    Log.i(TAG, ""+responseBody.length());

    // Parse
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
    Log.i(TAG, ""+jArray.length());
    Log.i(TAG, ""+jArray.toString());
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
<snip>
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not iterating the json array. What is your Log.i(TAG, ""+jArray.length()); result? Is it greater than 0 ?

Comment: yes, it's > 0, e.g., if I print out the attributes of `String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost,responseHandler);` I get the following: `responseBody.length(): 17`
`responseBody: {"avgfft":[""]} `